# ObservableCollection not garbage collected unless it is manually set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, garbage-collection

In a WPF app, I have a XAML window which opens up another window and sets its DataContext to an instance of a ViewModel class. Among other things, a ListView in the view is bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.

The ViewModel loads about 7,000 items when it is initialized, and the ListView displays them (in a VirtualizedStackPanel).

In VS2015's debug performance monitors, I noticed that after the second window is closed, and there are no more references (as far as I know) to the ViewModel that contains the 7,000 items, those items still persist in memory. They survive several garbage collections of generations 0, 1 and 2 (and they are not in the LOH).

After a long investigation, I found out that setting the entier collection of 7,000 items to null when the window is closing, and making sure an OnPropertyChanged event is raised, causes this collection of items to be collected immediately. Trying to follow this collection to its roots in the VS heap snapshot tool is impoosible, since they are supposedly linked to a mess of XAML controls and elements.

My question is: is this normal behavior? Do you have to null out my objects all the time? What could I be missing?

Comment: "that after the second window is closed" - how exactly?

Comment: Closed from the window's close button. The XAML's code behind has methods for the Closed and Closing events, who both call the ViewModel to cleanup some objects.

Comment: Did you try to set the DataContext to null?

Comment: Not really. Should I? If the window goes out of scope and it's the only object that has a reference to the ViewModel, why would I have to do that?

Comment: Does the window really go out of scope?  Nothing in your MainWin / MVVM framework / DI that could hold a reference?  Verify with a destructor, set a breakpoint in it. It should get hit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - good call on that finalizer, and let me correct what I wrote: the 2nd window has no reason to stay in scope. However, it DOES stay in scope. When I use VS's diagnostic tools to follow the roots, I see that the window supposedly has references from pretty much every UI element in the XAML file. There are too many "roots" on the list to readh any helpful conclusion. How does that make sense?

Comment: References from its _own_ XAML file are normal and harmless. But do investigate what else happens with the handle. It's time for a [MCVE] if you want more help form this site.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this is that you have done *something* inside the second XAML Window View that has subscribed to an event in a non-weak way on the ViewModel. You need not worry about View-to-VM subscriptions done by Windows because these are weak by default so they don't leak. I'd start by looking for Behaviors you have written that might subscribe to VM events for example `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` or `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`.